# Serializer that I can pull from byte by byte?

Tags: serialization

I'm looking for a serializer, in any language, that I can give something (an object, a struct containing other structs, a hashmap, etc), that then lets me pull the serialized result from it byte by byte? And crucially, the serializer can't allocate an unbounded vector to store the bytes intermediately.

The API I'm thinking of, in Rust-like notation:

```rust
struct Serializer<T: serde::Serialize>(_);

impl<T: serde::Serialize> Serializer<T> {
    fn new() -> Serializer<T>;
    fn push(&mut self) -> Option<impl FnOnce(T)>;
    fn pull(&mut self) -> Option<impl FnOnce()->u8>;
}
```

i.e. I can `push` a `T` where `T` implements `serde::Serialize`; and I can `pull` `u8`s; either operation may "block" (by returning `Option::None`) if awaiting the other operation; and the memory allocations of `Serializer` are bounded.

Are there any examples of this? And what would it be called? I'm not really sure what to google..?